# Temp TableSpace Usage

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

we have a Job in our system which is processing data in bulk, so some user complain Application is slow while job is running, from AWR report we observed Temp table space waits even Temp tables pace is 32GB with auto extend on, is there any way to check what was the temp table space usage at JOB execution time. mean can we check history usage of table space. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--#1: Find the maximum temporary tablespace used during a snapshot.
select begin_time, end_time, instance_number, round(maxval/1024/1024) temp_mb
from dba_hist_sysmetric_summary
where metric_name = 'Temp Space Used'
order by 1,2,3;

--#2: Find SQL statements running around the same time.
--Look for the event it was waiting on.  Was it waiting on something like
--"resumable session", implying that no temporary tablespace was available?  Or was it
--waiting on reading and writing temporary tablespace because of large data or a bad plan?
select sql_id, event, round(temp_space_allocated)/1024/1024 temp_mb, sql_plan_line_id,
    dba_hist_active_sess_history.*
from dba_hist_active_sess_history
where sample_time between timestamp '2017-12-03 12:00:00' and timestamp '2017-12-03 13:00:00'
order by sample_time desc;

--#3: Find the slow operation in the SQL Monitor Report.  (If you're using AWR you probably 
--have also licensed the diagnostics pack, and can use this tool.)  Find the operation that
--used too much temporary tablespace and try to figure out why.  Are the objects simply
--too large for the temporary tablespace?  Is there a cross join creating a huge
--intermediate result set?  Is the execution plan bad and Oracle is sorting/hashing
--result sets poorly?
select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => '[enter SQL_ID from above]') from dual;
```